Craftsman style cross head without gluing
I would like to build some simple Craftsman style cross heads in the style shown below. I think it would be neat to make these out of a single piece of wood, instead of gluing. I was wondering if someone could suggest a good technique. It’s nearly a simple dado cut, but I’m not sure how to handle the offset reveals at the corners.


Welcome to WSE.  I am not sure I understand what part of the operation you are questioning.  Are you referring to the removal of material in the center ~3" as the dado cut? In which case it is the same operation at 90 degrees to make the entire profile. What tools do you have (router, saws, chisels)?

I call this an x/y problem. Everybody and their dog has been making these out of 3 pieces of wood for over a century.

A single piece of wood is going to be much more susceptible to twisting and warping.

"I’m not sure how to handle the offset reveals at the corners" If you go ahead with making this from a single piece of wood and you're already set up to mill out the centre as a dado then you can keep the same setup, flip the workpiece to vertical. Any number of quick setups could be made to do this safely. Then you simply adjust the cut height and start nibbling away. Of course you could also do this by sawing the shoulders and chopping away the waste with chisels, perhaps perfecting the long surface with a router but that's not an essential. You could also easily do this with a router jig.

@gnicko, I had the same initial reaction until I hoisted in the the modest dimensions. Careful selection of stock could offset most worries we'd normally have for something like this made from the solid.
